# In Magento how to find the customer's visit is from the Google Results Page

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, google-analytics

As we are moving from the classic google analytics to the Universal google analytics for the marketing requirement, i need to find out from where the customer is coming from. If he is coming from the marketing campaigns then we have the param **utm_source** from url. So with this I can find out the customer visit. But if the customer is from the google results, then there will be no extra parameters added to the URL.

Because of this, I am unable to differentiate whether the customer is from the Google Results or from the **direct URL** visit. My idea is to use, **HTTP_REFERRER**. But this will result in lot of requests to server for each page load which results in unnecessary load on server.

Universal google analytics does support **_utmz** cookies. It will only supported in classic google analytics. So is there any better way to differentiate the customer visit from the **google results** and the **direct URL** visit.